# fail to create new project on android studio after update

Tags: android, android-studio

This is not the first time that I have had to handle this issue.  It happens after updating the Android Studio.

When I create a simple new project I get this error message:

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.8/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
```

I open the link attached (https://docs.gradle.org/2.8/userguide/gradle_daemon.html) and but there's nothing to solve this issue.

Comment: I would like a permanent solution to this problem. I faced it a few times myself. Every time I had to either re-install my whole android-studio and at other times a simple restart made everything smooth. Weird!

Comment: ok, assume this solve the problem - is this a solution ?

Comment: I doubt that. Uninstalling a software isn't really a solution, it's kind of a work around. Reinstalling means reconfiguring everything. And that is a headache.

Comment: @Sajib Acharya i agree with you :: so how to solve it ? i did not found anything that can help us on this issue - but i found a lot of developers that handle this issue.

Comment: Your best bet is re-installing the JVM, then Android-Studio blah blah. But, that is not a concrete solution. I think this issue must be resolved immediately. Maybe it is a bug from Android-Studio's side. Just, maybe.

Comment: i'm sure this is a android studio issue. 
i can't understnand why the patch that fix this issue is not release yet.
just take too long of waiting and as i said before - this is not the first time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97774/discussion-between-sajib-acharya-and-yanshof).

Comment: Updated to 1.5 and now can't create a project that compiles, getting: android studio error retrieving parent for item